# Will I need a visa to leave the US in order to live in Sweden permanently?

Tags: customs-and-immigration

I'm currently a Jamaican immigrant living in the US. I'm not a green card holder nor am I a citizen but I do currently have DACA. I have family living in Sweden and would like to live there permanently. Would I need to obtain a visa from my home country and have it shipped to the US in order to travel to Sweden? Will I have any complications such as deportation at the airport?

Comment: You don't need a visa to leave the US, but you will need a visa to move to Sweden permanently. Our sister site [expatriates.stackexchange.com](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/) can help more with that (we only do short-term travel here, not permanent moves), but you'll need to supply more information about what basis you have for applying for Swedish residency.